# Using php to authenticate forum users for Kodi wizard

Tags: php, python, sql, kodi

about a month ago i decided to have a play with a KODI wizard, i edited it and learnt some basic python to help doing so. I think i now have added authentication into it.

The bit I'm struggling with is, i believe i need to create a php file on my server which i put the web address into the wizard. This then uses the php file to check against my forum (simple machines forum) to check the user login details are correct and then lets them use my wizard.

I've been looking for weeks for some correct php script but struggling, i don't mind sending some beer tokens for someone who can help with this,

Thanks!

```
def suminstall(redo=False):
if wiz.getS('login') == '' or wiz.getS('pass') == '' or redo == True:
    if redo == True: choice = 1
    else: choice = DIALOG.yesno(ADDONTITLE, "You are required to login to install builds from %s!" % ADDONTITLE, "Would you like to enter in your information?", "Visit %s to sign up!" % MEMBERS_URL, yeslabel="Enter Details", nolabel="No Cancel")
    if choice == 1: 
        login    = wiz.Get_Keyboard(wiz.getS('login'), 'Enter Your Login Email')
        password = wiz.Get_Keyboard(wiz.getS('pass'), 'Enter Your Password')
        wiz.setS('login', login)
        wiz.setS('pass', password)
    else:
        sys.exit()
url = "%s?email=%s&pass=%s" % (INSTALL_PAGE, wiz.getS('login'), wiz.getS('pass'))
link  = wiz.openURL(url).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
wiz.log(str(link))
total = re.compile('install="(\d)"').findall(link)
try:
    if (str(total[0]) == '1'):
        wiz.log("Login Successful!")
except: 
    if DIALOG.yesno('Authentication Failure', 'Please signup here: http://codeyking.com', 'Then Re-Enter the details', yeslabel="Re-Enter Details", nolabel="No Cancel"):
        suminstall(True)
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Don't simply link to your code in this way. It makes me very suspicious to run such an unknown script. Instead see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, think i have done it correctly now.